# ApI Call to authenticate is giving me "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, vue.js, routes

I have a Vue and .net application.
When I run "NPM start serve" it gives me the build

App running at:- Local:   http://localhost:8080/

However when I try and Log in it gives me this error:

> Console error:
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED     localhost:50463/user/authenticate:1

When I update axios.service.js file to use the 8080 port as I taught that would fix the error it gives me CORS headers are not present. Why would changing the port have this effect and how would I fix this?

I apologize if my question is not right or doesn't make sense I am new to .net and Vue but this seems like a routing issue ? I am not sure as the code was written by other developers and I am not as skilled.

axios.service.js

```
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:50463/';
axios.defaults.baseURL = API_URL;
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (a) => a,
    (error) => {
        if (!error.response) return Promise.reject({response: {data: 'Network Error'}});
        else if (error && error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
            store.dispatch('authentication/logout');
            router.push('/');
            window.location.replace('/');
            //
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);

export const SetBearerToken = function(token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null;
};

export const FilesUrl = API_URL + 'file/';
```

I tried changing the port in the API URL.

I tried adding the user that I log in with to the database but need some fields.
I then used a users details that is already in the database and still receive same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure both your front-end and back is running.
*ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED* looks like the API might not be running.
Looks like you API might be running on *localhost:50463* and your front-end is hosted is on *localhost:8080*.

When you change the port to 8080 it will point the front end back to himself since the front end is hosted on *localhost:8080*.

To start front-end:

```
npm serve
```

To start backend:

```
dotnet run
```